# Remove item by value from array with different keys

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to create a function that removes a word from my JSON file.

Function:

```
function removeword(lang,word) {

  var farr = [];
  var count = 0;

  fs.readFile('./dictionary.json', 'utf8', (err, jsonString) => {
    var items = JSON.parse(jsonString);

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      console.log(items[lang][i]);
      if (word === items[lang][i]) {
        items[lang].splice(i, 1);
      }
    }

    console.log(items);

     fs.writeFile("./dictionary.json", JSON.stringify(items), function(err){
           if (err) throw err;
           console.log('Done!');
     });

  });
}
```

Original JSON:

```
{"en":["moon","crazy"],"pt":["macaco", "macarrão"],"es":["hola"]}
```

by calling removeword('pt', 'macaco'), here's what I expect:

```
{"en":["moon","crazy"],"pt":["macarrão"],"es":["hola"]}
```

Comment: That's an Object

Comment: An object has no `.length`. And where is `lang` coming from?

Comment: @Ivan given the array, I want to pass a specific word and remove from array.

Comment: do you also pass the key for where the word exists?

Comment: @NickParsons I made some edits, it should be more clear now, could you reopen?

Comment: @IgorO looks better now - it is now more understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `.filter()` on your `items` array for the given key, you pass. For any element in your array which isn't your value, you can keep it by returning `true` (`v !== value`), otherwise, you can remove it (by returning false):

```js
const items = {"en":["moon","crazy"],"pt":["macaco", "macarrão"],"es":["hola"]};

function removeword(obj, key, value) {
  obj[key] = obj[key].filter(v => v !== value);
}

removeword(items, 'pt', 'macaco');
console.log(items); // {"en":["moon","crazy"],"pt":["macarrão"],"es":["hola"]}
```

If you don't want to modify your `items` array (and instead return a new modified `items` array) you can use `Object.fromEntries()` to create a new object from the `[key, value]` pair arrays, where you can filter the `value`  array if the `key` matches your passed in key:

```js
const items = {"en":["moon","crazy"],"pt":["macaco", "macarrão"],"es":["hola"]};

const removeword = (obj, key, value) => Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(obj).map(([k, arr]) => k === key ? [k, arr.filter(v => v !== value)] : [k, arr])
    );

const result = removeword(items, 'pt', 'macaco');
console.log(result); // {"en":["moon","crazy"],"pt":["macarrão"],"es":["hola"]}
```

<sup>See [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries#Browser_compatibility) for `Object.fromEntries()`</sup>

A slightly more browser compatible version of the immutable method above would be to use `.reduce()`:

```js
const items = {"en":["moon","crazy"],"pt":["macaco", "macarrão"],"es":["hola"]};

const removeword = (obj, key, value) => 
  Object.keys(obj).reduce((o, k) => ({...o, [k]: k === key ? obj[k].filter(v => v !== value) : obj[k]}), {})

const result = removeword(items, 'pt', 'macaco');
console.log(result); // {"en":["moon","crazy"],"pt":["macarrão"],"es":["hola"]}
```

Comment: Thank you @Nick Parsons, I used the first solution with the .filter

Comment: @IgorO no worries :)